# why number of string should be greater than or equal to number of states in pumping lemma?

Tags: pumping-lemma

If `L` is a regular language, then there exists a constant `n` (which depends on `L`) such that for every string `w` in the language `L`, such that the length of `w` is greater than or equal to `n`, we can divide `w` into three strings, `w = xyz`.

```
w = length of string. n = Number of States.
```

Why should we pick `w` greater than or equal to `n`?
and what is Pumping length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the complete statement of the lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages), you can see that it is actually stating that every string is formed by a prefix `x`, a part that can be repeated any number of times `y` and a suffix `z`. Now it is obvious that, in the shortest case (when the repeating part is taken only once), the length of `w` equals the number of states needed for the language. This Wikipedia image is very useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pumping-Lemma_xyz_svg.svg

Comment: What happens when I take number of string less than number of states?

Comment: Given that prefix and postfix MUST be matched (otherwise, the string doesn't belong to `L`), then the repeating part was taken zero times. So, `y` is empty, its length is zero, and this does not satisfy the pumping lemma. So, to satisfy it, a string MUST be longer than the number of states.

Comment: You are saying that if the `w` is lesser than `m`, then there will be no looping and pumping lemma will not pump that string?

Comment: If you take a string shorter than `n`, you are missing the loop. So `y` has length 0. But the lemma says that `y` is longer than 0. So the string does not satisfy the lemma. Because of this, one of the hypoteses says that the string must be longer than some `p` (the pumping length, that is the number of states a finite automaton needs).

Comment: I think that the formal statement of the wikipedia article is very clear. If you didn't, I suggest you to read it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding the lemma (which you also have not stated completely), and mixing aspects of a *proof* with what you did state.  The lemma says that for every regular language `L`, there is a constant `p` such that every string of at least `p` symbols that belongs to `L` has a non-empty substring of length no greater than `p` that can be "pumped", always yielding another element of `L`.  The constant `p` is the (a) "pumping length".

This can be proved by observing that if a language is regular then there is a finite state automaton that accepts it, and taking `p` to be the number of states in that automaton (details omitted).

That does not imply, however, that the number of states in the smallest FSA the recognizes a given regular language is the smallest possible pumping length for that language.  For instance, consider the language consisting of the union of { `a`<sup>`n`</sup> } and { `b`<sup>`n`</sup> } for all `n`.  You need a four-state FSA to recognize this language, but its minimum pumping length is 1.